# How to include node_modules to bundle for production?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm creating a NodeJS application using TypeScript and packed with Webpack. When creating the bundle, all external modules are not imported which leads to path error.

Google, Stackoverflow, nothing relevant information for my case.

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
  .filter(function (x) {
    return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
  })
  .forEach(function (mod) {
    nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
  });

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './src/proxy/main.ts',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, '../../'), 'dist/proxy')
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      test: /\.js($|\?)/i
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js'],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin()]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: nodeModules
};
```

**Externals is fine for development but when it comes to production, I need all external libs to be bundled up in main.js.**

Comment: If you want the dependencies to be included, why have you set [`externals`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)?

Comment: > "Externals is fine for development but when it comes to production, I need all external libs to be bundled up in main.js."

Comment: This seems to be your production config, though; it sets `mode` to `production`. If you want different settings in dev and prod, you'll need different config files.

Comment: True but that is irrelevant, I may be wrong but I think you can flag the mode using `webpack --mode`, no ? Would it be possible to give a specific behavior to the way webpack behaves whether the mode is production or development ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that - as I said above, you use different config files: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to comment the externals property but quickly rolled back since I get many warnings (e.g. `Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest to keep your config file this way, with externals, it's a lot more convenient and performance wise. I assume you are moving your bundle to another directory so make sure to also move your `node_modules/` or node will not find the dependencies.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question